# Searching concatenated field

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`, `users`.`id`, 
CONCAT(firstname," " ,lastname) AS `users.firstnamelastname`, 
CONCAT(lastname," " ,firstname) AS `users.lastnamefirstname` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE (id != '15') 
AND (firstnamelastname like 'a%' ) 
OR (lastnamefirstname like 'a%')
```

The above code I am using to search against a concated field but the above is not working. Is there anyone sql guru to help me out.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error message or just incorrect results?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or T-SQL? Your question's tagged with both.

Comment: He's trying to use aliases in the query without using HAVING. However, creating an alias such as `users.firstnamelastname` is just terrible, alias it without specifying the source (`users.`) and read up on HAVING keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`, `users`.`id`, 
    CONCAT(firstname," " ,lastname) AS `firstnamelastname`, 
    CONCAT(lastname," " ,firstname) AS `lastnamefirstname` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE (id != '15')
)
WHERE (firstnamelastname like 'a%' ) 
OR (lastnamefirstname like 'a%')
```

Your aliases are not available to MySQL when it's first evaluating the `WHERE` clause.

But your query actually equals this:

```
SELECT `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`, `users`.`id`, 
CONCAT(firstname," " ,lastname) AS `firstnamelastname`, 
CONCAT(lastname," " ,firstname) AS `lastnamefirstname` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE (id != '15')
AND (firstname LIKE 'a%' OR lastname LIKE 'a%')
```

So your concat in the where clause is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have redundant braces in where try

```
WHERE (id != '15') 
AND (firstnamelastname like 'a%' OR lastnamefirstname like 'a%')
```