# Searching for concatenated plant names

Tags: php, mysql, database, concatenation

i am writing a programme in **PHP** to search plant names in a collection database. You should be able to type a scientific plant name (e.g. Rumex acetosa or Medicago x varia) to find all entrys on that name.  the plant names are atomised, so every name consists of two to five parts. i don't want to search on each of the parts separately, but i need to add them all up to one name.

So what I tried to do is write a `SELECT CONCAT` clause.

```
$sql = "
  SELECT observationid, fullnamestring, latitudedecimal, longitudedecimal
  FROM  observation, (
    SELECT CONCAT (genusormonomial, firstepithet, rank, hybridflag, intraspecificepithet)
    FROM name
  ) name_str, name, gatheringsitecoordinates 
  WHERE name.nameid = observation.fkname
    AND gatheringsitecoordinates.sitecoordinateid = observation.fkgatheringsite
    AND (
      SELECT CONCAT (genusormonomial, firstepithet, rank, hybridflag, intraspecificepithet)
      FROM name
    ) name_str LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($sucharray[0]) . "'
";
```

Unfortunately it simply doesn't work this way because he complains about the syntax of my query.

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your **MySQL server** version for the right syntax to use near `name_str LIKE 'rum%'` at line 2

To give you a idea what it should look like in the end browse http://bgbm3.bgbm.fu-berlin.de/iopi/gpc/query.asp

i am a total Sql-newb so maybe someone of you can help me out!

Thanks!

P.S.: i already looked at the thread [Searching concatenated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121475/searching-concatenated-field) but this won'T do, because i really need to search the whole name, not only each of its parts.

Comment: OK the reason you have a syntax error is because you are trying to use a table alias where one doesn't belong - remove the last `name_str` and the *syntax* will be OK, but the query still won't work. What you need to do is use explicit `JOIN`s. Your field list is ambiguous and your have not tied `gatheringsitecoordinates` or the derived table into the rest of the results by matching a column against other tables. You shouldn't need to perform the derived table query twice, you should just need to `JOIN` it on and use a field from it for the `LIKE`. Can you explain you table schema a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `WHERE` clause - like this...

```
... epithet ) FROM name ) WHERE name_str LIKE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has subqueries with no named columns.  My nearest guess is that you want something like this:

```
SELECT observationid, fullnamestring, latitudedecimal, longitudedecimal
FROM  observation o join
      (SELECT CONCAT(genusormonomial, firstepithet, rank, hybridflag, intraspecificepithet) as name_str,
              name.*
       FROM name
      ) n
      on o.nameid = n.nameid
WHERE o.sitecoordinateid = o.fkgatheringsite AND
      namestr like <'" . mysql_real_escape_string($sucharray[0]) . "'>
```

However, this is a problem with gatheringsitecoordinates.sitecoordinateid, since there is no table called gatheringsitecoordinates.  Above, I assumed it was part of the observation.  If it is a separate table, then you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT observationid, fullnamestring, latitudedecimal, longitudedecimal
FROM  observation o join
      (SELECT CONCAT(genusormonomial, firstepithet, rank, hybridflag, intraspecificepithet) as name_str,
              name.*
       FROM name
      ) n
      on o.nameid = n.nameid join
      gatheringsitecoordinates gsc
      on o.sitecoordinateid = o.fkgatheringsite 
WHERE namestr like <'" . mysql_real_escape_string($sucharray[0]) . "'>
```

Also, I've expressed this as regular sql without the string notation.

Comment: The Table Schema is as follows: Observation, Name, Gatheringsitecoordinates

Observation to Name (n:1)
Observation to Gatheringsitecoordinates (n:1)

Inside the tables there are relevant columns as follows:
Observation: observationid, fkgatheringsite, fkname
Name: nameid, genusormonomial, firstepithet, rank, hybridflag, intraspecificepithet, fullnamestring
Gatheringsitecoordinates: sitecoodinateid, latitudedecimal, longitudedecimal


genusormonomial: Cannabis, firstepithet: sativa, rank: subsp., hybridflag:(NULL), intraspecificepithet: sativa
 -> Cannabis sativa subsp. sativa

Comment: I tried to do it like you said but it returns an error. Error: Unknown column 'sed' in 'where clause'
 or Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 2
 depending on what i type in the search field.

What does the ON statement do in the FROM part?

Comment: The "on" statement gives the conditions for joining two tables together.  It is the standard syntax for joins, which should be explained in the documentation for any database.